# How to understand isNaN

Tags: d3.js

I try below code block, the isNaN return true. The value is not NaN why the return value is true?

```
true 06-19 12:20:30.200
```

```js
        var t = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")("2022-06-19 12:20:30.200");
        v = d3.timeFormat("%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")(t)
        var isNan = isNaN(v)
        console.log(isNan,v)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Number.isNaN() instead. The global version of isNaN() has some [confusing behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior).

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN.

```js
        var t = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")("2022-06-19 12:20:30.200");
        v = d3.timeFormat("%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")(t)
        var isNan = Number.isNaN(v)
        console.log(isNan,v)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```